# is the strategy pattern a good choice to fetch the same information from different sources?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm writing a "master" API call that pulls the same information from different vendors.

For example, let's assume that there are 2 vendors and I have access to their respective REST APIs to pull the friends list from user Jane:

vendor 1 gives me **some** friends from Jane.

vendor 2 also gives me **some** friends from Jane, but the list of friends that vendor 2 gives me may (or may not) be different from the list of friends that vendor 1 gives me.

I need to write a script that pulls the list from both vendors, combine them and remove duplicates from them.

I'm thinking about using the strategy pattern to accomplish this, so that I can swap API calls implementations in runtime, but I wonder if this is a good case for such pattern.

If it isn't, then what design pattern would allow me to have a variable number of API calls implementations, and letting me add more if needed overtime?

The language I'm planning to use is PHP, if that influences your answer.

Comment: Just do it, the important thing is a solution that works preferably SOLID code. Don't think about what patterns you should use if you're not certain it's already a good solution. The name of a pattern or even if you're using one it doesn't matter.

Comment: Don't listen to @MikeSW :)  In the real world you usually won't see things that are named after their patterns but good code usually *does* fit the structure of the standard design patterns so it is definitely worthwhile to be thinking about this... though after you've done it for a while it will just become second nature and won't be something you explicitly pause to reflect on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me the key thing you want to avoid here is mixing your code that combines and dedupes your lists with the logic needed to make the API calls. A design pattern you should look at would be a Repository pattern. Not knowing the intricacies of the situation Here is how I would lay it out:

Each object that works with an API should implement the same "FriendRepository" interface that allows you to get the list of friends.

Then you would have your FriendCompiler class that has a list of FriendRepository interfaces. In your code you would iterate over the list of FriendRepositories getting the friends and compiling the finalized list. The FriendCompiler class would be unaware of the implementation details of any API and the List allows you to add, change or remove FriendRepositories from the FriendCompiler class at runtime.

Comment: Repository is essentially just a specialized version of Strategy

Answer (score 2):

Strategy = pattern 'whereby an algorithm's behaviour can be selected at runtime' (Wikipedia). Therefore, it suggests that it's a suitable pattern for your problem.